# Car speed not more then 100 km/h

Tags: transmission, volvo

I have a 2004 Volvo XC70. Normally if I travel at 110 km/h my engine speed is at 2400 RPM. Now I have to press accelerator up tо 3000 RPM, but max speed is 100 km/h and won't go higher. This problem just started and I'm not driving now. Engine has new spark plugs. May there be any problems with automatic transmission? АТF fluid not dirty, but maybe has to be changеd? Тhank you.

Comment: Valeriy, can you tell what gear the car is in?

Comment: It's automatic transmission. I think my transmission can't switch to last (highest) gear.

Comment: OK, but can you tell exactly what gear it's in?  Sounds like it's missing more than top gear for that difference in engine RPM.

Comment: I think last gear missing